# pandas dataframe loc usage: what does supplying length of index to loc actually mean?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have read about dataframe `loc`. I could not understand why the length of `dataframe(indexPD)` is being supplied to `loc` as a first argument. Basically what does this `loc` indicate?

```
tp_DataFrame = pd.DataFrame(columns=list(props_file_data["PART_HEADER"].split("|")))

indexPD = len(tp_DataFrame)

tp_DataFrame.loc[indexPD, 'item_id'] = something
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is simply telling pandas you want to do the operation on all of the rows of that column of your dataframe. Consider this pandas Dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(zip([1,2,3], [4,5,6]), columns=['a', 'b'])

   a  b
0  1  4
1  2  5
2  3  6
```

Your transformation `df.loc[len(df), 'b'] = -1` is equivalent to `df.loc[:, 'b'] = -1`. You are applying this `-1` transformation to all rows of the desired column, both yield:

```
   a  b
0  1 -1
1  2 -1
2  3 -1
```

The purpose of the first argument is so you specify which **indices in that column will suffer the transformation**. For instance, if you only want the first 2 rows to suffer the transformation then you can specify it like this:

```
df.loc[[0,1], 'b'] = -1

   a  b
0  1 -1
1  2 -1
2  3  6
```

Comment: No worries, if you could accept the answer I would very much appreciate it!